# Where is my error in accessing a wikipedia infobox via javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, onload

Where is my error in accessing a wikipedia infobox via javascript?
(I'm using codeigniter framework)

**Page Controller**

```
    $data = array(
               'title' => 'My Title',
               'country' => 'My Heading'
          );

    $countrycodes = ['au', 'us'];
    $countrynames = ['Australia', 'United_States'];
    error_log(print_r($page, TRUE)); 
    $key = array_search($page, $countrycodes);
    error_log(print_r($key, TRUE)); 
    if($key !=null){
    $data['country'] = $countrynames[$key];
    }

    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->helper('utility');

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
    if(!is_null($key)){
    $this->load->view('templates/infobox', $data);  
    }
    $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
```

**au page**

...

```
<div style =" position:absolute;top:90%; background: red;">
<?php echo $country; ?></div> // prints Australia.
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/country.js"></script>
// variable isnt formed yet to be picked up  by javascript.
```

**infobox template**

```
<div class='info-box' id="<?php echo $country; ?>">
    <table id ="result">
</div>
```

**country javascript**

```
$(window).load(function(){
        var searchTerm= $(".info-box").attr("id");

        alert(searchTerm);
        //searchTerm= "Australia";

        var url="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page=" + searchTerm+"&redirects&prop=text&callback=?";
        $.getJSON(url,function(data){
          wikiHTML = data.parse.text["*"];
          $wikiDOM = $("<document>"+wikiHTML+"</document>");
          $("#result").append($wikiDOM.find('.infobox').html());
        });
});
```

I've also tried the body onload = "function();"

[image: browser source]

Comment: I think your error analysis is wrong. First, all of PHP runs. All variables are echoed. Then the page is sent to the browser. Then javascript runs. If it doesn't work with Javascript, then inspect the source code for errors. Maybe PHP printed something wrong. Maybe Javascript is fetching something wrong. But there is NO timing problem of PHP running too late for Javascript.

Comment: Where is the function base_url()

Comment: I agree with @Sven that the premise of the question is wrong. It's a pure Javascript problem. From what I can see, you're trying to get the value of country from the wrong div (it's not in an .info-box div).

Comment: that ordering makes sense, thanks Sven. 
but i'm still abit confused. it is definitely in the info-box div (see edit). i guess there must be a syntax error.

Comment: ok i got it working now. i think it was a case of me forgetting to put the onload function call but thinking that i did.

Answer (score 0):

using the body onload = "function();" did work. i think i forgot to put a line in, and jumped the gun.

```
function loadWiki(){
        var searchTerm= $(".info-box").attr("id");

        var url="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page=" + searchTerm+"&redirects&prop=text&callback=?";
        $.getJSON(url,function(data){
          wikiHTML = data.parse.text["*"];
          $wikiDOM = $("<document>"+wikiHTML+"</document>");
          $("#result").append($wikiDOM.find('.infobox').html());
        });
    }
```